# Cordova - Enable "Code Sign on Copy" for iOS framework in plugin.xml

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, ios-frameworks

I am using a third-party iOS framework in a cordova plugin and I got it working, but it requires me to add it as an embedded framework. My `plugin.xml` file has this line:

```xml
<framework src="src/ios/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework" weak="false" custom="true" />
```

The reason I set `weak=false` is because the when I build my app while it is only linked, I get this error when I run it in Xcode:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ReactiveCocoa.framework/ReactiveCocoa
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07ED2E5F-BDD3-4E9A-968A-1139C618F3CD/PhasorTag.app/PhasorTag
Reason: image not found
```

Setting `weak=false` solved that, but then the App installation would always fail while deploying

```
2015-12-07 18:24:10.735 ios-deploy[46090:4986918] [ cordova run ios --device --verbose ] 
Error 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. 
AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: -d,-b,/Users/k/repos/phasor-tag-firebase/platforms/ios/build/device/PhasorTag.app
```

The solution to this is to check off **Code Sign on Copy** in the Xcode project file under **BuildPhases** > **Embedded Frameworks** for ReactiveCocoa. From what I saw in Cordova's documentation this is not possible to automate with Cordova's `plugin.xml` file. *What is the best way to have this process automated?* I think I can solve it by using a hook to insert the **Code Sign on Copy** attribute into the `project.pbxproj` file so the framework can be code signed when built, but that is annoying to do every time a framework gets added. It would make more sense if there was an xml attribute for this in Cordova.

Another thing I'm unsure of is whether there is another way to build the ReactiveCocoa framework so it doesn't have this issue in the first place. If anyone knows, please enlighten me.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem during deployment on iPhone 6S+, for all prior devices (5S, 4S) deployment was passed successfully. @thekenner33 which device have you used?

Comment: @thekenner33 did you find a solution to this? I am having a very similar issue

Comment: @Skeep No, I tried writing a cordova after-plugin-install hook to edit the `project.pbxproj` file to include the *Code Sign on Copy* setting, but it just crashed xcode. The difference between the scripted copy and the manually checked copy I believe was the ordering of the framework entries, but I wasn't sure. It wasn't worth continuing at that point.